# I'm looking for a formula for Round Table Business Networking.

Tags: combinatorics

I run Business Networking Events. And I'm looking for a formula that can be applied in the following circumstances.

Scenario:

A number of business people attend a networking event.

There are a number of round tables with 5 place at each table.

Each attendee has 1 min to present their business to their table companions.

After everyone at each table has presented, the attendees move to a new table and repeat the process.

I'm looking for a formula that gets each attendee to a new table with 4 'new' companions every time they move.

There is usually a Table Captain who doesn't move.

Example:

20 people on 4 tables of 5

Each table is lettered A to D

Each person is numbered 1 to 5

How do I get each person from Table A (and the other tables) to meet all the other attendees easily and without confusion.

Such as all people with a No 2 move to table B and then move to a different table...?

Paul Ashbury